# boto3 AWS MediaConvert unknown "ImageInserter" parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have followed aws-samples configuration to create job template in MediaConvert with job as follows:

```
{
 ...
 "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "TimecodeSource": "EMBEDDED",
        "FileInput": "s3://rodeolabz-us-west-2/vodconsole/VANLIFE.m2ts",
        "ImageInserter": {
          "InsertableImages": [
            {
              "Opacity": 50,
              "ImageInserterInput": "IMAGE_URL",
              "Layer": 0,
              "ImageX": 0,
              "ImageY": 100,
              "Width": 242,
              "Height": 97
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

but when I'm running the job, I received an error as follows:

> Unknown parameter in Settings.Inputs[0]: "ImageInserter", must be one of: AudioSelectorGroups, AudioSelectors, CaptionSelectors, DeblockFilter, DenoiseFilter, FileInput, FilterEnable, FilterStrength, InputClippings, ProgramNumber, PsiControl, TimecodeSource, VideoSelector

Reference for Boto3 MediaConvert: [MediaConvert — Boto 3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mediaconvert.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your version of `boto3`:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.9.116'
```

If you have an older version, update with:

```
sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade
```